# Get full URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want get the full url of a page request using htaccess
My code is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^(.*)\.html$   session_page2.php?page=$1  [NC,L]
```

But in session_page2.php the `$GET` variable prints as follows

```
Array
(
    [page] => rfiregtoday
)
```

where my actual url is `http://localhost/xxxx/rfiregtoday.html#2009CalgaryWEBC`

I want to get `rfiregtoday.html#2009CalgaryWEBC` any idea how to do this?

Comment: There is no way to access to the URL hash in .htaccess. This is a client-side technique and isn't revealed to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the original request path. This will not include the hash because that is never given to the server in an http request. I suggest you change it to a get parameter like `mypage.html?hash=foobar`.

If you want the GET parameters available in PHP after a redirect, use the `QSA` flag in your `RewriteRule`. This will add GET parameters to the rewrite, and make them available in PHP with `$_GET`.

More info about the QSA flag here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule